# adding class to an element selected with :contains

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i tried to do this :

```
var selec = $("li:Contains('"+ $("#main").val() +"')");
selec.eq(1).addClass("virtual");
```

And my css :

```
.virtual
{
    backgroung:red;
    color:white;
}
```

And html looks something like this

```
<input type="text" id="main" />
<div id="bottom-div">
<ol>
    <li>Content1</li>
    <li>Content2</li>
    <li>Content3</li>
    <li>Content4</li>
    <li>Content5</li>
    <li>Content6</li>
    <li>Content7</li>
    <li>Content8</li>
    <li>Content9</li>
    <li>Content10</li>
    <li>Content11</li>
    <li>Content12</li>
    <li>Content13</li>
</ol>
</div>
<div id="apparent-div">Apparent div</div>
ContentContent Conetent<br />
ContentContent Conetent<br />
ContentContent Conetent<br />
ContentContent Conetent<br />
ContentContent Conetent<br />
ContentContent Conetent<br />
ContentContent Conetent<br />
ContentContent Conetent<br />
<div id="key"></div>
```

The javascript perfectly shows the content i want but it doesnt adds the class to it why ?

Where have i been going wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to [work](http://jsfiddle.net/uy5Ns/), you had an error in your CSS:

```
.virtual
{
    backgroung:red; //Was mispelled
    color:white;
}
```

**should be:**

```
.virtual
{
    background:red;
    color:white;
}
```

**The following isn't apparently the cause of the problem :) :**

and you had `Contains` as opposed to `contains` in your Javascript.

```
var selec = $("li:Contains('"+ $("#main").val() +"')");
```

**should be:**

```
var selec = $("li:contains('"+ $("#main").val() +"')");
```

Comment: OH YEA I AM SERIOUSLY BLIND GAh

Comment: And i defined Contains as case in sensitive :S i forgot to myention it here oops

Answer (score 1):

1) typo in css: `backgroung:red;` = `background:red;`

2) "contains", not "Contains" `var selec = $("li:contains('"+ $("#main").val() +"')");`

3) select results are zero-based: `selec.eq(0).addClass("virtual");`

Comment: Just the typo mistake in css nothing else :D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pLx5w/1/) should work. You had `Contains` instead of `contains`.

Comment: No. i defined :Contains as case in sensitive so that isnt wrong i actually misspelled background

Comment: Ah. I totally missed that! And I didn't realise that `contains` was meant to be capitalized.

Comment: Neither did I Andrew - I made both the changes as once, and assume the contains was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var selec = $("li:contains('"+ $("#main").val() +"')");
selec.eq(1).addClass("virtual");
```

Comment: Dude as i said it perfectly selects but doesnt adds the class. I made a spelling mistake :S

Comment: @kritya - `contains` is case sensitive so it will not select the text

Comment: But anyways the issue was in the css class :)

Comment: i binded the Contains as case in-sensitive one so i forgot to mention it here :S